# BroadcastReceiver receiving when it shouldn't

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

Hello everybody and thanks in advance.

I use a BroadcastReceiver to receive data from a dialog of another activity. This dialog has both positive and negative buttons code. Here it is...

```
                inflador = li.inflate(R.layout.dialogo_estandar, null);

            MensajeDialogoTV = (TextView) inflador.findViewById(R.id.dialogoEstandarTV);
            MensajeDialogoTV.setTextSize(tamanoTexto);
            MensajeDialogoTV.setText(miActividad.getResources().getString(R.string.ac_dialogos_06));

            ventana = new AlertDialog.Builder(miActividad);
            ventana.setIcon(R.drawable.icono_info);
            ventana.setTitle(miActividad.getResources().getString(R.string.ac_dialogos_05));
            ventana.setView(inflador);

            ventana.setPositiveButton(miActividad.getResources().getString(R.string.estandar_SI), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int boton) {
                    finish();
                    miActividad.finish();
                }
            });

            ventana.setNegativeButton(miActividad.getResources().getString(R.string.estandar_NO), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int boton) {

                    Intent RTReturn = new Intent(PrincipalActivity.BROADCAST_REINICIA_CRONO);
                    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(miActividad).sendBroadcast(RTReturn);
                }
            });

            return ventana.create();
```

then, in the call activity PrincipalActivity.java, I have the receiver like this...

```
    int PASOS_POR_EL_RECEIVER = 1;
static final String BROADCAST_REINICIA_CRONO = "REINICIA_CRONO_BROADCAST";

private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        if(intent.getAction().equals(BROADCAST_REINICIA_CRONO))
        {
                Log.e("TONI-LOG", "PASANDO POR EL RECEIVER " + PASOS_POR_EL_RECEIVER++ + " VECES.");

                broadcastManager.unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
        }
    }
};
```

and I call the dialog from this activity like this...

```
            broadcastManager.registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, intentFilter);

        Dialogos Dialog = new Dialogos();
        Dialog.Dialogo1(this, DIALOGO_INTERRUMPIR_TEST, TamanoTexto1, 0, null, tipoDispositivo);
```

the log line increments a counter each time the execution goes through the receiver, but the "strange" thing is that, watching the log in Android Studio, shows the line even when I touch the positive button on the dialog, wich has no "sendbroadcast" line.

Can anybody tell me why this happens?.

Thanks a lot again!!!

Comment: But if you touch positive button is activity finished or not ?

Comment: Yes, it closes but I don´t know why goes into the receiver. I do some stuff inside the receiver that only should be executed when the negative button is pressed.

Comment: And you are calling sendBroadcast only in that negative button click listener? Are you sure you are not sending by mistake events from other sides? Maybe you could use the find usages feature from AndroidStudio to find out about that.. and also, I guess it should worth adding a breakpoint into your negative click listener and see if that isn't called somehow..

Comment: Ok Cata, I found the problem. It was a setOnDismissListener in that dialog. I had the sendbroadcast inside it too. The thing is that I thought that this method only triggered when you touch outside the dialog, but it seems to trigger always that the dialog is closed, even if it does touching one of its buttons.

Thank you all for your time and sorry about my mistake.